# Argument of type X is not assignable to parameter of type Y

Tags: node.js, typescript, syntax-error

```
async acquireToken(request: AuthenticationParameters, redirect: any) {
  return msalApp.acquireTokenSilent(request).catch(error => {
    if (requiresInteraction(error.errorCode)) {
      return redirect
    } else {
      console.error('Non-interactive error:', error.errorCode)
    }
  });
}
```

The Error:

```
Argument of type '(error: any) => void | Promise<AuthResponse>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(reason: any) => AuthResponse | PromiseLike<AuthResponse>'.
```

How do I make the type assignable to the parameter type it wants?

Comment: Please consider editing the code above to constitute a [mcve] as described in [ask], suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) so that others can reproduce your issue and advise you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your function must return an `AuthResponse` or a Promise of one. Your error handler has a path that returns nothing. You should return something in that path, like this:

```
async acquireToken(request: AuthenticationParameters, redirect: any) {
  return msalApp.acquireTokenSilent(request).catch(error => {
    if (requiresInteraction(error.errorCode)) {
      return redirect
    } else {
      console.error('Non-interactive error:', error.errorCode)
      return error
    }
  });
}
```